# Does the attribute name length of Python objects has effect on performance?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, dictionary, interpreter

Python objects keep attributes in the `__dict__` dictionaries (unless you are using `__slots__`), and you can assign an arbitrary string as an attribute of an object at runtime using `setattr()` for example. This means that every time an attribute is accessed or assigned, the interpreter must perform the string hashing of the attribute name to get it's value from the dictionary, which is more expensive the longer is the string. Could this affect performance in small programs where the cost of attribute name's hashing is comparable to everything else the program is doing?

Also, if I understand correctly, this doesn't apply to regular variable names since in the bytecode they are converted into some kind of integer indices, right?

Comment: If the script is small then what difference does it make? The whole script takes negligible time.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer seems to be that CPython interpreter doesn't actually compute the attribute name's hash on every attribute access. Instead, it applies string interning, meaning that it keeps a single copy of most compile-time string constants (including variable/function/attribute/etc names, and even dictionary keys), and compares their references whenever they appear in code, which are simple integer comparisons. This probably doesn't apply to identifiers created at runtime, such as using `setattr()`.

Thanks to @jasonharper for the pointer.